# is Date() show in debug broken in swift5/Xcode11?

Tags: swift, xcode

when i debug in xcode 11, and all the Date type not showing.

like this one:

```
(lldb) p fileValues.contentModificationDate!
(Date) $R48 = {}
(lldb) p Date()
(Date) $R50 = {}
```

[image]

but NSDate is fine, so is really wired.

**update**
user po can show the vale:

```
po newWD.modDate
▿ Optional<Date>
  ▿ some : 2019-11-08 05:36:29 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 594884189.6275711
```

but in this windows, it's really not should be show as nil.
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `p` and not `po`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor po is work very well, wired...i update a pic, the problem is not right at variant windows as left.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `.description` the debugger will display correctly

So (and my background here is weak, so happy to be corrected) the CustomStringConvertible protocol still seems to be implemented, but I wonder if the subscription to it has been lost somewhere so the debugger doesn't output it by default?

Comment: or maybe it's just another XCode 11 bug :-/

Comment: i think you maybe right, check my picture update.